# traceroute -T -p 25 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com

Tags: postfix-mta

When I am sending emails my log says connection timed out.

when I ran traceroute: `traceroute -T -p 25 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com` , I am getting the following output.

```
traceroute to alt4.aspmx.l.google.com (74.125.141.27), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Any ideas how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

To check connectivity run `telnet alt4.aspmx.l.google.com 25` and on other screen run `tcpdump -i any port 25 or icmp`
And then analyze tcpdump output